# Calculating arrangements using the multinomial coefficient

Tags: probability

> The students $A,B,C$ are in a group of 28 students, which is randomly split in 7 groups of 4 people each.
>
> - In how many ways can the students be arranged in seven teams of 4?
> - And what's the probability that any two of $A,B,C$ are in the same group?

So I thought you could do this with a multinomial coefficient: $$A=$$$$28 \choose 4,4,4,4,4,4,4 $$

But apparently, you have to divide this answer by $7!$ *Can anybody explain why?* (it says because there are $7!$ double counts, but I don't understand why)

And for the second part. There are three ways that any of the two are in the same group: $(A,B); (A,C) ; (B,C)$.

So the total amount of possibilities are $A$, and the possibilities we want are what I thought $26\choose 2,4,4,4,4,4,4 $ $\times 3$ because there are 3 ways in which it could happen, but this is also wrong. *Can anybody explain why?*

Comment: The order of the $7$ groups is not important, that's why.

Comment: @barakmanos So in a multinomial coefficient, there is an order within the groups? I didn't know that.

Comment: Not sure how to answer this question, but in your calcultaion, the order of the groups is important.

Comment: @barakmanos I think I get the first part now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a mistake to treat multinomial coefficients as the answer to a question, because it tempts you to memorize instead of understanding. It is far better to solve the problem directly, and then to observe, *having solved and understood the problem*, that the answer can be described in terms of a multinomial coefficient.

First, write out a list of the 28 students. You know that this can be done in $28!$ ways.

Treat the first four students as being in the first group, the next four in the second group, and so on. Then ask the question: "How much of an over-estimate is $28!$ of the number of possible arrangements?"

1. Within each group, the order of the four students doesn't matter. You have therefore counted each group $4!$ times. All in all, this means you have over-estimated by a factor of $4!^7$.
2. But also, the order of the groups doesn't matter. By pretending that it did matter, you have over-estimated by a factor of $7!$.

All in all, therefore, $28!$ is $4!^7\times 7!$ larger than the true count of the number of possible arrangements. The number of arrangements is thus $$\frac{1}{7!}\frac{28!}{4!\times 4!\times 4!\times 4!\times 4!\times 4!\times 4!}\text,$$ which you are entirely free to express as a multinomial if you are fond of multinomials.